# Using angular-input-modified to retrieve the index?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am successfully using angular-input-modified to mark up when my form changes from it's original state. However, I have a form which is using an ng-repeat, and I need to work out which row has actually changed. I can't seem to see a way of getting that info in what angular-input-modified has to offer.

I can see that there is a modifedModels but it just lists the details of the element modified - no way for me to relate that back to the row it is in. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You set the name to contains the index.
i.e.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="member in orgMembers.users">
<td><select class="form-control" name="role[{{ $index }}]" ng-model="member.role" ng-options="r for r in roles track by r" required></select></td>
```

This is then accessible via `$modifiedModels[0].$name` which you can then extract the relevant info regarding which row was actually changed (and thus only send the entries that have changed).

Comment: I'm in a situation when `$modifiedModels` is not empty, but the whole form has has `modified` property set to `false`. How do I inspect why there's a mismatch? I thought if the form is not `modified` then `$modifiedModels` should be empty.